# Typescript generics and String Literal Types: Argument of type "OnBlur" is not assignable to parameter of type "T"

Tags: typescript, generics

If I specify that my generic in the `InputValidatorBinding` takes in a String Literal Type and that generic type is used in another class which generic type is a string type then why do I get a compile error?  Arn't they essentially the same?  The only difference is that the `InputValidatorBinding` has a tighter constraint where as `EventAggregator` is looser.  Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
type TextboxEvents = 'OnBlur' | 'WhileTyping' | 'WhileTypingThrottled';
type FormEvents = 'OnFormSubmit';
type DatepickerEvents = 'OnSelectDate' | 'OnCloseCalendar';
type WhenToProcessRule = TextboxEvents | FormEvents | DatepickerEvents;

class EventAggregator<T extends string> {
}

class InputValidatorBinding<T = WhenToProcessRule> {
   protected readonly eventAggregator: EventAggregator<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T = SomeType` in the generic type introduces a default for the generic type `T` but in no way constrains `T`. So `T` could be any type. If you want to both constrain and have a default you need to yous both `extends` and `=` (`T extends SomeType = SomeType`)

```
type TextboxEvents = 'OnBlur' | 'WhileTyping' | 'WhileTypingThrottled';
type FormEvents = 'OnFormSubmit';
type DatepickerEvents = 'OnSelectDate' | 'OnCloseCalendar';
type WhenToProcessRule = TextboxEvents | FormEvents | DatepickerEvents;

class EventAggregator<T extends string> {
}

class InputValidatorBinding<T extends WhenToProcessRule = WhenToProcessRule> {
   protected readonly eventAggregator!: EventAggregator<T>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewBGB7eBRAbhAdsAzlALxQDkA8jgEIA2ArgE6lQA+ZA6gBYCWNEM4bjgDmzNqS69+gkTE4MUwYHwAmpANwAoUJCgAxFAwC2WXAWJlKB4wGU6SI92Abt4aABEAhsAhhuAYwBrCAZTPEISChwbCD5-YC8fMUscAGEaFHwIVM8+HBVPJi0daC5cGBQABQV-CHx8ACU6Pgs4RFQMbHDWfUMTLvM2RN8A4NCB-C1NfxpPeqgw4ABBYWEGCGFvQwAeGCgEH3zCfGAGIWEAPigAb00AX01p2fmASRwwOmAANVzuAuBDFQhCpzrt9ohcCpCGUcBVqihavUmi0SDC4TU6o1mhArrcoPiwAofPEICooOtPCoUDgaCB9gMVmsNlsGABCABcCwZq3WmwBDF2Fy0dyAA)